# Who is the other Steve?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I happened to notice an unfamiliar domain in the source code, used to monitor Jobs traffic or something like that.

Being a curious person, and a web programmer, I browsed to the plain domain: https://clc.stackoverflow.com/

This resulted in a cryptic message:

> Hi. I'm Steve. But not that Steve. The other Steve.

So, who is Steve? Who is the other Steve? Are they dangerous?

Comment: Think of a big company. That had two founders. Both called Steve. Not that Steve. The other Steve.

Comment: @Oded awesome! Won't you post this as answer?

Comment: *Are they dangerous* ... not if you wear your tin-foil hat ...

Comment: @ShadowWizard - frankly, that's just my guess. Turns out - it is wrong.

Comment: @Oded but it was just brilliant... so what is the correct answer?

Comment: I don't know. I was just told it has nothing to do with Apple.

Comment: Alan,Alan, Alan, Alan, Alan!

Comment: We hope [not this one](https://xkcd.com/1672/)

Comment: What is that domain and why does uBlock block it?

Comment: @Oriol it's used instead of adzerk to redirect users to the proper company page when seeing the sidebar ads, e.g. [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ItPG1.png). You can see the URL, it's pointing to a page on clc.stackoverflow.com domain. As for uBlock it's probably blocking the [tracking beacon](https://clc.stackoverflow.com/soi.gif), which is a hidden pixel

Comment: My current team at work is called "The Other Team". [Here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CfcsPi2UIAANOSN.jpg)

Comment: @Shyju lol, that's a good name! Now rename to "The Other Steve" and it would be even better... ;-)

Comment: @Shyju I suggest doing a better job of censoring info if you're going to do so, the obscured text may still be discernible from the visible portions.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We actually had another team called **Not the Other Team** for a while.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting company you work at, @Shyju. ;)

Comment: @Oded's comment is even better given the subdomain's role of monitoring Jobs traffic...

Comment: @MalcolmOcean I know, right? lol

Comment: But not this Steve, right?

Comment: Just don't ask about [Bruce](https://youtu.be/_f_p0CgPeyA).

Comment: I read the first sentence as `used to monitor Job's traffic` as someone would monitor a persons traffic and was very confused

Comment: Good observation

Comment: It offends the other Steve.

Comment: @Steve [you're not alone](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UidFk.png)! :-O

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think we definitely need a steve.stackexchange created.

Comment: @Steve yeah, but Dan is first. There are thousands of Dan's.

Comment: [Is there a limit?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneSteveLimit)

Comment: @Steve That would get my vote.

Comment: That domain (`clc.`) stands for **C**a**lc**ulon, the internal codename for the ads server. Everything in the project is Futurama themed.

Comment: @ArtOfCode thanks, I know already as it was [posted here as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279457/152859).

Comment: Took me 5 years to meet Steve. But not that Steve, the other Steve.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Sometimes we abbreviate our dev site as "dev.so"... which of course means dev.stackoverflow.com... but if you actually go to [dev.so](https://dev.so/), you get Steve. We're not that Steve, we're [the other Steve](https://stackexchange.com/users/1246026/stevvve).

Comment: The Steve who owns that domain is one hell of a lucky guy

Comment: @AwalGarg true, and it was registered only on June 24, 2013 according to [this](http://who.is/whois/dev.so). Too bad SE didn't buy the domain when they still could... ;-)

Comment: I find it quite suspicious that "Are they dangerous" was not answered...

Comment: And what is the `clc` the OP mentions?

Comment: In other news, traffic to the site, dev.so has increased exponentially since this post.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 I was wondering the same but cannot find something that fits http://www.abbreviations.com/CLC

Comment: @Ciro http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244102/for-what-is-clc-stackoverflow-com-used.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the link. It explains what it is, but I couldn't find what the acronym ? stands for.

Comment: @Ciro yeah, I also wonder. Bret here probably knows, hopefully he'll break the silence and share that sacred knowledge. ;)

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 it's a cryptic abbreviation for [**C**a**lc**ulon](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Calculon), the code name of our ad server.

Comment: We may eventually make a more useful homepage which says what it's for and why it's called what it's called. The point isn't to be secretive, it's just that most people don't care.

Comment: One thing is for sure, at least this other Steve has great design talent, maybe SO should give him an offer?  His site looks great!

Comment: Wow, that Steve rocks! The stuff to do [hashing](https://hash.dev.so) is great!

Comment: I recently [answered another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279457/171886) regarding the domain, if anybody would like a little additional info

Comment: @Sebastian "Don't Ask, Don't tell..."

Answer (score 13):

> used to monitor **Jobs** traffic or something like that

I highly doubt so, since [Steve Jobs has been dead for 4 years now](https://www.google.com/search?q=steve%20jobs%20death). This leaves us [Steve Wozniak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Wozniak) - along with every other Steve on this planet.

/joke

*edit: Fellow user Oded has already indicated this in the form of a cryptic riddle in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323297/who-is-the-other-steve/323405#comment345450_323297).*

Comment: Stealing the glory from [Oded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323297/who-is-the-other-steve/323405#comment345450_323297)? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Didn't meant to steal his glory. His comment is the most voted one (one of the upvote is mine). Anyway, I'll link to his comment.

Comment: lol, I was just kidding. Kudos for solving the riddle, took me a while too!

Comment: Your joke should be the accepted answer.